# Select a piece of text in a rich text box

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Hello I trying to select a piece of text in a rich text box in c#

for example:

the text in a rich text box is "Hello my friends !!"

and i want to select the text from "my" to the end
like this:

```
string myText="my friends !! ";
```

How??

Comment: What UI library are you using? Winforms? WPF? ASP.NET? Something else?

Answer (score 3):

The SelectionStart and SelectionLength are the properties needed here
And the initial position could be found using string.IndexOf

```
int pos = richTextBox.Text.IndexOf("my");
if(pos != -1)
{
    richTextBox.SelectionStart = pos;
    richTextBox.SelectionLength = richTextBox.Text.Length - pos;
    richTextBox.Focus();
}
```

to get the selected text back in a string var you write:

```
string myText = richTextBox.SelectedText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to do it by SendKeys

```
int linePosition = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("my");
richTextBox1.SelectionStart = linePosition;
richTextBox1.Focus();
SendKeys.Send("{HOME}+{END}");
SendKeys.Flush();
```